# Base URL for Django, Behind Nginx Proxy

Tags: python, django, nginx, weasyprint

I have a simple `Django` App, that is hosted behind `Nginx`. I'm using `weasyprint` to produce PDF reports. `weasyprint` requires a `base_url` property to access `static` files.

While the below `django` code works fine on local machine (under dev server), I get **502 Bad Gateway** error when publish it behind Nginx.

## View.py

```
html = render_to_string('admin/enquiry/quoterequest/generate.html', {'enquiry': enquiry})

response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')

response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename=\"Enquiry_{}.pdf'.format(enquiry.reference)
weasyprint.HTML(string=html,base_url=request.build_absolute_uri()).write_pdf(response, stylesheets=[
    weasyprint.CSS(settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0] + '/css/print.css')])
```

The above code works fine (without printing images), if I remove the `base_url` attribute. Would appreciate your input - either how to setup `nginx` or retrive the `base_url` from Django

## Nginx Config

```
# configuration of the server
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name 192.168.33.10;  # Vagrant IP
    root        /home/www/my_project;
    charset     utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 75M;   # max upload size

    location /media  {
        alias /home/www/my_project/assets/uploads;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/www/my_project/assets/static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

}
```

## print.css

```
@page {
  size: letter;
  margin: 1.5in .25in 1.9in .5in;

  @top-center {
    content: url("/uploads/header_footer/header.jpg");
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }

  @bottom-center {
    background-image: url("/uploads/header_footer/footer.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    content: "Page " counter(page);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: bottom;;
  }
}
```

This is the error message from `nginx` log.

```
upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.33.1, server: 192.168.33.10, request: "GET /enquiry/admin/enquiry/quoterequest/view/1/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8001/enquiry/admin/enquiry/quoterequest/view/1/", host: "192.168.33.10", referrer: "http://192.168.33.10/admin/enquiry/quoterequest/"
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own - but this is sort of workaround'. For so ip **192.168.33.10**, and for it's base address `http://192.168.33.10/media/'`base_url`parameter for`weasyprint` still has issues - even manually inputing the base address didn't do the trick.

**This still doesn't work and return with 502 Bad Gateway**

```
weasyprint.HTML(string=html, base_url='http://192.168.33.10/media/').write_pdf(response)
```

So I decided to change the `template`. So wherever I've an URL defined,  I changed them to...

```
<img src="http://{{ request.META.HTTP_HOST }}{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ myapp.mymodel.my_image }}">
```

and added `context_instance` in my `View.py` to get `MEDIA_URL`.  Hopefully someone will come up with an answer for `weasyprint`'s `base_url` issue.

```
html = render_to_string('admin/enquiry/quoterequest/generate.html', {'enquiry': enquiry}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')

response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename=\"Enquiry_{}.pdf'.format(enquiry.reference)

weasyprint.HTML(string=html,base_url=request.build_absolute_uri()).write_pdf(response, stylesheets=[
    weasyprint.CSS(settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0] + '/css/print.css')])
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with WeasyPrint, and what I found is that `base_url` is only taken into account [if URLs are not absolute](https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/blob/v0.42.3/weasyprint/urls.py#L113).

My workaround was to make a [custom Django template tag](https://gist.github.com/tadeo/c88ac1f6a482c65fbebe8961c6bc97f7) to translate them to file system absolute path if a truthy `absolute_paths` is present in the context. In the meanwhile [I posted a question about my own problem scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51102841/).

Hope this helps!